# String Replacement using UNIX shell script

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I want to do the string replacement in the following manner:

> ***Requirement:***

The output must be changed in line with the values from the reference file.

***Input:***

```
aaaa
val1=xxx
val2=yyy
val3=zzz
bbbb
val1=ppp
val2=qqq
val3=rrr
aaaa
val1=xxx
val2=yyy
val3=zzz
```

***Reference File:***

```
block   variable    value
aaaa    val1        iii
aaaa    val2        jjj
aaaa    val3        kkk
bbbb    val1        eee
bbbb    val2        fff
bbbb    val3        ggg
```

***Output:***

```
aaaa
val1=iii
val2=jjj
val3=kkk

bbbb
val1=eee
val2=fff
val3=ggg

aaaa
val1=iii
val2=jjj
val3=kkk
```

> ***Current Approach:***

Currently I tried to do this using Sed command. Using which I was able to replace 1 block of code, ie,

```
aaaa
val1=xxx
val2=yyy
val3=zzz
```

into,

```
aaaa
val1=iii
val2=jjj
val3=kkk
```

The val1,val2,val3 variables occur in both the blocks 'aaaa' and 'bbbb'. But for block 'aaaa' the values will be different and for block 'bbbb' the values will be different.
currently using 'sed' command I am able to replace the values for block 'aaaa', but for 'bbbb' block also the same values are being taken.

> ***Query:***

How to do a 'sed' command(or any other string replacement command) for a particular set of lines alone? My reqirement is, the control must check for the block names and then fetch the relavant values for the variables from the reference file.

It would be of great help if someone can give me a solution.

> Thanks!
>
> Ra-V.

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry in advance if this answer does not help, but I am unable to leave a comment so have to post here*. 
Have you tried using grep in combination with sed? You should be able to do something like this:

`grep bbbb filename | sed phrase to replace`

Comment: Thanks for your comments! 
I did use,
 
> sed -i '/baz/4,6s/foo/bar/' filename.txt
 
My problem here is we are parameterising all the values, which would make it something like this,

> sed -i '' "$baz" '/' "$Line_START" ',' "$Line_END" 's/' "$old_val" '/' "$new_val" '/' filename.txt

This creates some syntax error and problem. 
In a nutshell, the line numbers and all the string values are dynamic and are hence passed in as variables.

Is there any better way of doing it? Please correct me....

Answer (score 0):

Your question ought to be edited.  I am ignoring all of it except "How to do a 'sed' command(or any other string replacement command) for a particular set of lines alone?" which seems to be the heart of the question.

sed accepts addresses.  To specify specific lines by line number:

```
sed -e '4,6s/foo/bar/'
```

will replace the first instance of 'foo' with 'bar', but only on line 4 to 6.

```
sed -e '/baz/s/foo/bar/'
```

will do the replacement only on lines that match the pattern 'baz'.

```
sed -e '/baz/{/qux/s/foo/bar/; }'
```

will do the replacement only on lines that match the pattern 'baz' *and* the pattern 'qux'.

There are many ways to specify the lines on which you wish to execute a sed command.  Reading the documentation may help.  (ie `man sed`). In other words, RTFM.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! 
I did use,
 
> sed -i '/baz/4,6s/foo/bar/' filename.txt
  
as suggested by you.
My problem here is we are parameterising all the values, which would make it something like this,

> sed -i '' "$baz" '/' "$Line_START" ',' "$Line_END" 's/' "$old_val" '/' "$new_val" '/' filename.txt

This creates some syntax error and problem. 
In a nutshell, the line numbers and all the string values are dynamic and are hence passed in as variables.

Is there any better way of doing it? Please correct me....

Comment: `sed -e "$START,${END}s/$PATTERN/$REPL/" -e "$S2,${E2}s/$PATT2/$REPL2/"`