# string replacement using awk command

Tags: unix, awk, sed

This is a continuation to my previous post [string replacement using awk command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012648/string-replacement-using-awk-command) which is not 100% fully resolved.. To make it clearer..

(The source file and code I am using are at the bottom of the post)

**requirement 1**

If I dont have a lookup data(Eg, for "u_no" is not in the reference file, the current solution prints an empty field.

```
aaaa
uid=1a1a
pwd=1b1b
u_no=
```

I want that to pick the value from the source file instead..

```
aaaa
uid=1a1a
pwd=1b1b
u_no=12345
```

**requirement 2**

If the data in the source file or reference file is mixed up, it should still do the replacement properly.

That is, when the ref file is changed like this:

```
block,parameter,value
aaaa,uid,1a1a
aaaa,pwd,1b1b
bbbb,uid,2a2a
zzzz,pwd,9b9b
zzzz,uid,9a9a
bbbb,pwd,2b2b
```

**For this, I am getting**

```
aaaa
uid=1a1a
pwd=1b1b
u_no=
bbbb
uid=2a2a
pwd=9b9b
zzzz
uid=9a9a
pwd=2b2b
```

** I must get**

```
aaaa
uid=1a1a
pwd=1b1b
u_no=12345    #points to my req 1 
bbbb
uid=2a2a
pwd=2b2b
zzzz
uid=9a9a
pwd=9b9b
```

I want the search and replace to happen based on the blocks `aaaa,bbbb,zzzz,etc..` Not sequentially. (For eg, here the `pwd` value for `bbbb` should be `2b2b` and not `9b9b`).

**source file**(src.txt)

```
aaaa
uid=xxxx
pwd=nnnn
u_no=12345
bbbb
uid=yyyy
pwd=eeee
zzzz
uid=yyyy
pwd=eeee
```

Note `uid` and `pwd` value for `bbbb` is same as that of `zzzz` in `src` file.

**reference file**(ref.txt)

```
block,parameter,value
aaaa,uid,1a1a
aaaa,pwd,1b1b
bbbb,uid,2a2a
zzzz,pwd,9b9b
zzzz,uid,9a9a
bbbb,pwd,2b2b
```

Note: The order of records in the ref file might also change as I mentioned in requirement 2. The lookup value for `uid` and `pwd` for `bbbb` is different than that of `zzzz`. But I need the result as follows:-

**Required Output file**(src_out.txt)(including the requirements 1 and 2)

```
aaaa
uid=1a1a
pwd=1b1b
u_no=12345
bbbb
uid=2a2a
pwd=2b2b
zzzz
uid=9a9a
pwd=9b9b
```

**Code**

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "[,=]+" }
NR==FNR {
    if (NR>1) {
        map[$1,$2] = $3
    }
    next
}
{
    if (NF==1) {
        key = $0
    }
    else {
        $0 = $1 "=" map[key,tolower($1)]
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk ref.txt src.txt
```

This works fine for my initial expectation, but the `requirement 1` and `requirement 2` which I specified here are now added and so I need the solution for these.

Comment: What have  you tried to solve this?

Comment: Edit your question to make it MUCH clearer and more explicit what the difference is between this and your previous questions (http://stackoverflow.com/q/28963149/1745001 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/28849774/1745001) as I for one can't see any difference at all, and also tell us in what way(s) the previous solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28965212/1745001) does not work for your new requirements (whatever they are) - show the output it produces for comparison with the output you want. You need to put more thought and effort into asking the question so we can help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search replace string in a file based on column in other file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327179/search-replace-string-in-a-file-based-on-column-in-other-file)

Comment: @EdMorton -- Edited the post....Explained it as much as I can! ... Please have a look now... Thanks for your patience...! :-)

Comment: @Jotne -- please find the edited post.... :-)

Comment: @Sanish yes, now it is clear so I've posted an updated solution to only use the ref data if it exists. As I've said repeatedly, the original script is completely independent of the order of lines in the ref file so idk why you keep bringing that up. The script I provided simply CANNOT do what you say it does above and mix up the values given the input files you show - all it does is map keys to values, no magic and no order implied. THINK about it and insert print statements if it's not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution with  `awk`

```
awk -F= '
FNR==NR {
    split($0,b,",")
    a[b[1] FS b[2]]=b[3]
    next} 
!/=/ {
    f=$1
    print
    next} 
    {
    print $1"="(a[f FS $1]?a[f FS $1]:$2)}
' ref.txt src.txt
aaaa
uid=1a1a
pwd=1b1b
u_no=12345
bbbb
uid=2a2a
pwd=2b2b
zzzz
uid=9a9a
pwd=9b9b
```

Comment: It works fine... If in case I need to send parameters into the AWK program.. how to send here? ... here I want to take 3rd column or 4th column or 5th column from the reference file based on certain conditions.... so the key would become either... a[b[1] FS b[2]]=b[3].....or.... a[b[1] FS b[2]]=b[4].....or.....a[b[1] FS b[2]]=b[5]...while reading the reference file.... how to parameterize this b[...]... ???

Comment: @Sanish Read my answer regarding getting data inn to `awk` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script

Comment: Sir... It helped a lot... thanks... I am using Sun OS 5.10... It is showing a syntax error for the line in your code...."!/=/ {" .... is there a workaround for this? ..... but it worked pretty well in red hat....

Comment: This `!/=/ {` test if the line does not contain `=` and should work on all version of `awk`.  You can try to replace it with `$0!~/=/ {`

Comment: @Sanish Use nawk (new awk) or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (POSIX awk) with Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked to test for the presence of the src values in the ref file:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "[,=]+" }
NR==FNR {
    if (NR>1) {
        map[$1,$2] = $3
    }
    next
}
{
    if (NF==1) {
        key = $0
    }
    else if ( (key,tolower($1)) in map ) {
        $0 = $1 "=" map[key,tolower($1)]
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk ref.txt src.txt
aaaa
uid=1a1a
pwd=1b1b
u_no=12345
bbbb
uid=2a2a
pwd=2b2b
zzzz
uid=9a9a
pwd=9b9b
```

Comment: Will check and let you know sir... Thanks! :)